# Restful way to validate a resource

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Imagine I have a resource of a some special case of an e-commerce application /cart in my API that supports some CRUD operations: GET, POST

I want to have a service that validates if the cart is correct (stock availability, etc...) so I need all the cart information, but I don't want to store partial states of the cart, that's why PUT is not supported for this resource.

The question is which method and path is the correct to do this kind of service in a Restful way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to build a restful web service, you should not bind too much business logic in it.

Restful service should be think as an infrastructure of the system. It provides consistent api to allow others to access the resource.

You could build a bussiness layer upon the restful resources, in this layer you can do the complex business logic, for example, checking stock availability(maybe underlying accessing the stock resource), or making a payment(maybe underlying accessing the payment resources and the product resources)

Comment: I think you are right. The validate logic will have to be on the Rest client using other Rest resources (payment, stock,...)

The problem is that my client will be a smartphone so it's quite important to be CPU and network friendly... I expect to have something like a method HEAD for a POST.

Let me explain: Method HEAD is for getting metadata information of a resource, if its available or some metadata information of the resource. It will be perfect for me is to do something similar to this but for a POST.

If it's not possible your solution is the Restful best way to deal with it.

Comment: I think using HEAD may be a little weird... since the validation logic and processing logic are separated into two request, there may be some unsafety. In fact, although the concept of rest is very popular, it's very hard to design it well, most api just seems to be restful(esspecialy the url pattern). I recommend you to build a business api upon the rest api, or just putting the validation logic in the post method(no need to sticking to the rest concept).

Comment: Thank you, finally I'm not going to support a validation service, so I'm going to do the valitation only at the POST method. If later the validation is need I'll do a business API. :)